# Spinner get its data from array resources programmatically

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to get a Spinner from an XML to be populated with data from R.array.myData in code. I tried few things and read few posts but for some reason I can not cut it.

Line #2 is not happy with the method args.

```
        String[] data = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gender);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
        ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(ad);
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: `Line #2 is not happy with the method args` : what it saying? probably due to first argument? try to pass `activity` instead of `this`

Comment: Yes. activity is it. Thank you.